# Create User Rights Screen in WPF/C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, binding

I have a many-to-many relationship setup in MSSQL like this:

[image: User Rights relationship]

*(One user can have zero to many rights and one right can belong to zero to many users)*

And I'm trying to create a screen to manage the rights for a single user like this using WPF and C#:

[image: User rights screen]

But I'm struggling on how to represent a many-to-many database relationship in a screen that is is one-to-many relationship (one user, many rights). I wanted to be able to check/uncheck a right and have it added/removed from that user's rights array with as much WPF as possible without having to write a bunch of clunky/hacky C# code.

*NOTE: I am using EDMX to convert my SQL tables to C# classes.*

My current WPF for the data grid is just:

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid" MinHeight="100" ItemsSource="{Binding RightsList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="True" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
```

Comment: Well, the binding and data model are sufficient for that job. The magic part is/has to be in the code between both and we do not see.

Comment: BTW stop thinking about many-to-many, you want to present a single user and that is a simple list of all rights which are set or not

Comment: What you call clunky/hacky code is actually necessary. WPF is best used when you use the MVVM pattern. For that pattern you need to write code. You cannot just expect your entity model to be sufficient unless you want to build your entity model and db model specifically for the view which will be a poor design.

Comment: @CodingYoshi - It's not that I don't want to write *any* code. It's that I don't want it to just be unnecessary and clunky code (due to not knowing how to do it properly).

Comment: Look at your view: it has a single user and many rights. Some rights will be given to the user by checking it. Others will not be given. You need a viewmodel which has a user and a collection of rights. Each right will have a property `Granted` which will be bound to the checkbox. Your view is one to many. Your db model is many to many. Thats fine. During saving you will take the userid from the viewmodel (one id) and zero or more rights and insert many records into the `UserRight` table. These records will have the same userid but different rightids for one user.

Answer (score 0):

If I was you I would have a rights control that uses its own UserRightsViewModel and have that ViewModel as a property in the UserViewModel. Assuming you have a UserViewModel.Save(), that would call a UserRightsViewModel.Save() to Save the rights correct. The DataGrid in UserRights would be a checked list, and you just save those that are checked.